# Distinct with 10 unique records of one column

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem with my SQL query. I'm trying to get a result of the image below but I only want @tag_names which some of them are duplicates to be shown only for like 10 times. Is there a statement that works like DISTINCT but for 10 records per each unique @tag_name?

I've tried this but no success:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag_name
              , int_value
              , real_value
              , bool_value
              , datetime 
           FROM waardes 
          WHERE machine_id LIKE 3 
          GROUP 
             BY tag_name 
          ORDER 
             BY tag_name
```

[image: Table]

Thanks already.

Comment: Don't use distinct and `GROUP BY` together . You can use `HAVING COUNT(*) > 10` .

Comment: But HAVING COUNT(*) > 10 only for @tag_names which are duplicates?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What? Please don't use images. Show some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use variables to count 10 for each `tag_name`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT *,
             @rn := if( @tag_name = tag_name,
                        @rn + 1,
                        if(@tag_name := tag_name, 1, 1)
                      ) as tag_count
      FROM waardes 
      CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0, @tag_name := '') as vars
      ORDER BY tag_name
     ) as T          
WHERE tag_count <= 10
```

Realize here you order by `tag_name` so the 10 are random, if you want be more specific add another condition on the `ORDER` (ex: date)

Comment: I'm not getting any results here. What im trying to create here, is a query which returns a maximum record of 10 per unique tag_names, their values can be different. So for example if i got 28 tag_names "test", i only want the last 10 tag_names with their values to be returned. All of this im trying dynamic for each tagname.

Comment: All the variables are NULL.

Comment: Also here `SELECT @rn := 0, @tag_name := ''` , please try again. Sorry :(

Comment: Im not sure what results im getting here, i've got 9 records with the tag_name ="iphone 5" but its variable says 1.

Comment: Now its counting, but how do i only show the last 10 results "order by datetime"?

Comment: I use `< 10` instead of `<=10` what variable say 1?

Comment: That is another question.  if is only the last 10 without tag_name you do `ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 10` other wise change `ORDER BY tag_name, datetime DESC`